# How to get info from crash dump of python

Tags: python, gdb, gdb-python

I have a python server running (cherrypy webserver). When a URL `/a` is hit, it uses `ctypes` to call a C library function. The library function is causing a seg-fault which results in the python server crashing and generating a 250MB crash dump.

If I use gdb: `gdb python python-dump.core` then it only shows that the stacktrace has `libc.so` calls to abort and exit.

Is there a way to get the name of the python function which was last called? And possibly the python variables' values?

I have tried calling the same function directly from a daemon written in C and gdb is able to give me exact function name which is calling the culprit function and the values passed. Is there a way to have the same level of detail when the crash dump is from a python process?